# Word VBA, Finding price and giving a alert

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm currently writing a macro to find the total price of an order. So I'm actually wanting the macro to find "Totaal"(total) in the Word doc and select the next word what's the total price of the order.

For example, Total € 9.900,78 Select 9.900,78

```
With ActiveDocument.Range
    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .Execute FindText:="Totaal"
        Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=2
        With Selection
            .MoveEndUntil Cset:=",", Count:=wdForward
            .MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=0, Extend:=wdExtend
        End With
    End With
    Do While .Find.Found
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        .Find.Execute
    Loop
End With
```

Then if its selected it should make a msgbox if the selection/price is above a certain price. But I have actually no clue how to make that function. I really hope you guys could help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
Sub Test()
Dim Amt As Single
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Text = "Totaal €?@[0-9,.]{1,}"
    .Execute
    End With
    Do While .Find.Found
      Amt = CSng(Trim(Split(.Text, "€")(1)))
      If Amt > 1000 Then MsgBox Amt
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      .Find.Execute
    Loop
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, got it working now

```js
Dim Amt As Single
Dim gedaan As Variant
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Text = "Totaal?€?@[0-9;.]{1;}"
    .Execute
    End With
    Do While .Find.Found
      Amt = CSng(Trim(Split(.Text, "€")(1)))
      If Amt > 15000 Then MsgBox "Je moet 10/80/10 factuur maken!!"
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      .Find.Execute
    gedaan = InputBox("Schrijf hier iets als je dat heb gedaan", "Gedaan", "")
    If StrPtr(gedaan) = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Orderbevestiging word afgesloten!")
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf gedaan = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox ("Orderbevestiging word afgesloten!")
    Exit Sub
    Else
        MsgBox ("We gaan verder met de orderbevestiging ")
    End If
    Loop
End With
```